# Is it possible to render a large number of shapefiles to a pdf document using Python?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile

I'm extremely new to GIS, and recently made a map by loading a bunch of shapefiles into QGIS using a python script. However, it took 15 mins to scroll in or out on the image, and the pdf export crashed the program (I attribute both to the number of shapefiles, it was several thousand).

Is there a way to take all the shapefiles in python and output them to a pdf document? I only want black lines and I only want one line style so the only complicated part is dealing with the sheer number of them.

Alternatively, is there a trick I missed with exporting massive pdfs in QGIS?

====================

Edit for details:

The dataset I'm trying to render is the TIGER/Line USGIS data, specifically the All Roads set. There are 3,108 shapefiles, each in a subdirectory.

I have successfully pulled all this into QGIS using a Python script, set the line styles using another little tool I found, and then exported it as a png file at 1200 dpi (it refused to go higher). However, while the png file does look cool, I am unsatisfied with the quality of the print I can create from it. When the printer prints a raster graphic, the subpixel rendering makes result look washed out and blurry.

My goal is to send a vector document to the printer so that I can print this map without the greyed out look caused by subpixel rendering in a raster graphic.

So, to phrase my question better, what is the best way to create and print a ridiculously complicated document made of a huge pile of shapefiles? I use PDF just because I'm used to abusing it with LaTeX to make cool stuff, but is there a better way? I'm happy to go as deep into the code as possible, GUI just gets in the way when there's this much data and the result is visually so simple.

I was able to create a workflow where I exported the file from QGIS and then turned it into a vector pdf with a `potrace` script and then printed it with an `lp` script (I'm on Mac) which looks amazing for my state but does not work at the scale of the whole country.

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of the number of shapefiles, number of features in each shapefile, and (on average) the number of vertices per feature? It sounds like you are just asking way too much of the PDF format.

Comment: @blah238 That's likely, I use LaTeX a lot so pdf abuse is just my go-to format whenever I want something to print nicely. Basically I was using all the Tiger/Line all roads data from all 3,000 or so counties across the U.S.  I did actually get it exported as a ping at 1200 dpi, but I can't export anything higher than that and I want to be able to print without the grayness and loss of contrast caused by subpixel rendering. I did convert that png image into a vector pdf using a `potrace` script, but the final file was 168mb and crashes the print driver even when I print from command line `lp`.

Comment: @blah238 I'm hoping there's a way to make a file straight from the vector source, instead of tracing it which adds a lot of unnecessary complexity and loss of quality. I plan on printing the final document across multiple pages using `pdfposter` to distribute the workload. Am I just completely using the wrong format?

Comment: It's recommended that you [edit your question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/121901/edit) to add those kinds of details rather than expound in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use QGIS, but with ArcGIS, PDF export has always been tricky, especially with large datasets, at [small scales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_%28map%29#Large_scale.2C_medium_scale.2C_small_scale) and with poorly designed map documents.

In general, I don't think PDF is a good geographic data visualization format because it has no concept of [scale-dependent visibility](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000008000000), [generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartographic_generalization), etc.

But as it is the most popular "print" format, sometimes you just have to work with it. However, if you are using it purely for printing, [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) might be better. I think QGIS has a PostScript exporter you could try.

A better format for viewing with web browsers, mobile devices, etc. is a [tiled web map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map), where the tiles are pre-rendered at various scale levels and systematically requested and displayed by the client depending on the current view extent and scale. This is how, for example, Google Maps works.

So depending on whether you are building for paper, desktop or the web will inform how you design the map.

Ultimately, I think generalization is going to be the key here, because the sheer number of vertices you are pushing is too much for the machine to handle. You might try using [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) and/or [mapshaper](http://www.mapshaper.org/) to try to whittle down the size of the data. It looks like there is also a [QGIS plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/generalizer/) for generalization.

Comment: I'll try postscript, thanks! Yes, I'm designing for print, my png file is already pretty good for the screen.